# SAS Metadata DATA STEP Functions

Tags: sas, metadata, sas-macro, sas-metadata

I want to know why is the `metadata_getnatr` function is used with `metadata_resolve` function when we are trying to read the metadata through data step functions.

For example: in the code that is covered in the [link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrmeta/70119/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1lfiylg4nenwyn1oe66yco3sgly.htm)

Reproduced Here:

**Example 1: Using an Object URI**

```
data _null_;
    length id $20
       type $256;
    rc=metadata_resolve("omsobj:Machine?@Name='bluedog'",type,id);
    put rc=;
    put id=;
    put type=;
run;
```

**Example 2: Using a Repository URI**

```
data _null_;
    length id $20
       type $256
       attr $256
       value $256;

    rc=metadata_resolve("omsobj:RepositoryBase?@Name='myrepos'",type,id);

    put rc=;
    put id=;
    put type=;
    n=1;
    rc=1;
    do while(rc>=0);


rc=metadata_getnatr("omsobj:RepositoryBase?@Name='myrepos'",n,attr,value);
        if (rc>=0) then put attr=;
        if (rc>=0) then put value=;
        n=n+1;

    end;
run;
```

- Why are they using getnatr function?
- Does the metadata_resolve gives a URI as an Output or what is the output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I agree - the documentation here could be improved!

The first example is quite clear - provide a URI (metadata query) and return the type and Id to be used for further logic / queries.

The second example demonstrates something which is a bit of an edge case.  It is using the REPO [namespace](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/omamodref/61849/HTML/default/viewer.htm#typehier.htm) (instead of the usual, SAS namespace) to return an object representing the repository (eg FOUNDATION).  You may have noticed that you cannot substitue the URI with the ID from the original `metadata_resolve` function (which you'd expect the example to be demonstrating, as an efficiency thing).  According to the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/omamodref/67417/HTML/default/viewer.htm#z1786625.htm), the RepositoryBase subclass *inherits* it's metadata id, so this may indicate why it cannot be referenced without using a URI.

In any case, to clarify the usage of `metadata_resolve`:

- It's not mandatory to use it in combination with `metadata_getnatr`
- It's useful when you when you want to find out the metadata *type* returned from a URI
- It's useful when you are going to use the same uri in more than one query (so more efficient to turn it into an ID)

SAS will cache your query within the same metadata function, so unless you are going to use the same URI in more than one metadata function, you don't need to use `metadata_resolve`.